# Is there a way to apply a function on every two elemens?

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

If I have, for example, two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([1, 2])
```

I want to get the following result:

```
c = np.array([a[0]*b[0] - a[1]*b[1],a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[2], so on, a[0]*b[n-2] - a[1]*b[n-1]])
```

I m interested in a `numpy` convolution like method which can apply a custom function on the two arrays.
I tried convolution:

```
np.convolve(a, b)
```

but i cannot apply a custom function using convolution function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convolve` implies a sum, but you can make it subtract by just setting your second term negative:

```
b_neg = b.copy()
np.negative.at(b_neg, 1)
# or just b_neg = np.array([1, -2])
out = np.convolve(a, b_neg, node = 'valid')
```

That said, if you just want a custom function, you'll want @mrks answer

Answer (score 0):

I appears as if you're looking for `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`. You find the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter).

Example:

```
import functools
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter


def fun(input_chunk, coeffs):
    ... # calculate result
    return result

c = generic_filter(a, functools.partial(fun, coeffs=b), size=len(b))
```